# How do I handle different date format in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

In the date column of some dataset, I have the date column written in different formats. Not the usual number formats style, but with the days of the week and months spelt out. Some rows have the months spelt short, others have theirs spelt in full. Making it difficult to do a simple `pd.to_datetime(df,format)`. I thought about running a for loop. I split each row by '-':

```
for x in df['Date']:
   if len(i.split('-')[1])<=6:
```

But then I realized this wasn't a great condition. I am thinking the solution would be regex? What do I do?

[A sample of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SQaB.png)

Comment: can you provide a sample df

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate, you can use `.loc` with `.str` accessor splits:

```
df.loc[df['Date'].str.split('-',expand=True)[6].str.len()<=6,'Date']
```

You can assign anything if you like, or just get it.

Comment: Can you explain what this does? I tried it and got a key error then I decided to change the index from [6] to [1] and got some dates printed out that had the length of their months and date equal to 6. Which I said was not a good condition.